# Javascript parser generator

Tags: javascript, parsing, compiler-construction

I've seen some javascript parser generators:

1. Jison (http://zaach.github.com/jison/)
2. PEG.js (http://pegjs.majda.cz/)
3. ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/)
4. JS/CC (http://jscc.jmksf.com/)

Does any one have any experience with them?

What are the pros and cons? Are these libraries ready for production? And performance?

**EDIT**:
I want to parse and run a different language in javascript

Comment: This question should not have been closed as "not constructive". Asking for pros and cons of modules and programming tools is not in any way subjective.

Comment: I agree that this should not have been marked as "not constructive". For example the performance of JavaScript Parser generators can be measured using a [benchmark](http://sap.github.io/chevrotain/performance/) and a benchmark is not subjective...

Comment: My AGL parser builder is written in Kotlin common, so it can be used on any Kotlin target (JVM, JavaScript, native code, etc).

https://medium.com/@dr.david.h.akehurst/a-kotlin-multi-platform-parser-usable-from-a-jvm-or-javascript-59e870832a79

Comment: I recently wrote this parser combinator library called parsinator.js that supports state and debugging functionality: https://github.com/fresheneesz/parsinator.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want a parser generator that would spit a JavaScript written parser or a parser generator that would use a JavaScript grammar to build a JavaScript parser.

Anyway, I've only used ANTLR and JavaCC. ANTLR allows you to generate your parser in different languages (C, C#, Java) and it's pretty cool checking your Context-free grammar expressions on their GUI tree-like form. Never found a JavaScript grammar for it though.

JavaCC has a downside. Only generates the parser in Java. On the other hand, I found it easier to learn and to step from the part where you build the parser to - what I found to be the best part - building whatever you want around it e.g., code translator, rephraser, etc, etc.

Comment: I want to parse and run a different language in javascript.

Comment: @Atomble There's an online demo of Jison, so it's very easy to get started with it: http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/

Comment: JavaCC can be used together with GWT to generate JavaScript based parsers as per the following blog : http://consoliii.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/creating-gwt-compatible-parser-using.html

Answer (score 11):

I recently wrote this parser combinator library called parsinator.js that supports state and debugging functionality:

https://github.com/fresheneesz/parsinator.js

Old Answer:

PEG.js is incredibly easy to work with. Its "try online" feature is really useful in learning how to use the system quickly. I'm currently using it in the Rhino environment to parse a language I'm writing. I'm not a big fan of Rhino, but PEG.js sure is nice.