# What parser generators can generate Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, parser-generator

I am interested in writing a program using Javascript. This program will parse a custom scripting language. I'm looking for a list of parser generators to evaluate that target Javascript.

Comment: My AGL parser builder is written in Kotlin common, so it can be used on any Kotlin target (JVM, JavaScript, native code, etc).

https://medium.com/@dr.david.h.akehurst/a-kotlin-multi-platform-parser-usable-from-a-jvm-or-javascript-59e870832a79

Comment: I recently wrote this parser combinator library called parsinator.js that supports state and debugging functionality: http://github.com/fresheneesz/parsinator.js

Answer (score 0):

These answers were stolen from [Javascript parser generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211111/javascript-parser-generator). It would also be nice to have a list of the main features of each, or at least what type of grammar they take.

- [Jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/)
- [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/)
- [ANTLR 3](http://antlr3.org/)
- [JS/CC](http://jscc.phorward-software.com/)
- [Waxeye](http://waxeye.org/)