# Finding parts of a JavaScript expression

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, conditional-statements

Say I have a JavaScript expression as a string like so:

```
string = ' collections.users[ currentUsers[ ids[1].id ] ] && users[ ids[1].id ]'
```

Now I need to get some parts of this expression, they are **"dependencies"** for what I am doing.

This is what I need to extract from that string

```
result = [
         'collections.users[ currentUsers[ ids[1].id ] ]', 
          'currentUsers[ ids[1].id]', 'ids[1].id',
          'users[ ids[1].id ]', 'ids[1].id'
         ]
```

It Basically needs every "variable" that has `[*]`  in it

That is every variable that could cause the expression to change, I have been trying to do this for around 3 days now, what i have tried so far and failed is

1. Use a regex to find all of the dependencies **(fail)**
2. I have tried to split the string a use conditions like "if brackets open do something", but failed.

   It's just been really hard to figure out, I don't have anything I've tried in code because I've just been deleting and starting again.

I understand this could possibly be a bit "localized" but I have asked on the JavaScript chat for a few days for some advice and haven't gotten anywhere, I have no other option.

Anyone got any advice on how to achieve this, bearing in mind that this string is not static and may have deeper conditions?

Someone has suggested JSON for this but I don't see how that would work, what do you think?

Because of the nature of the question I'll give 50+ bounty the best answer/advice

Comment: I'd suggest to have a look at a proper JS syntax parser, such as http://esprima.org/.

Comment: @FelixKling OK, I've been thinking a lot about compilers but would it be too much just for something like this? I will look into that now, thanks

Comment: Depends. It would certainly work :) You can copy the content of your string here http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html and see the AST esprima would return, and decide if that's something you can work with or not. It would probably be the most reliable solution.

Comment: ok, cheers @FelixKling

Comment: Ha, the demo page even lets me create a unique URL, so just for reference, here is the AST that esprima would create for the code above: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=collections.users%5B%20currentUsers%5B%20ids%5B1%5D.id%20%5D%20%5D%20%26%26%20users%5B%20ids%5B1%5D.id%20%5D

Comment: JavaScript regex doesn't even have lookbehind assertions, let alone recursive capabilities. If this were php or perl, it is accomplished with a 5 line regex to find the outter container and a 4 line function to parse the inner containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably need to use a recursive function and iterate over each character. Each time you hit an open bracket, you enter a new layer of recursion; each time you hit a close bracket, you exit one.

I believe this gives you exactly what you want.

```
var toParse = 'collections.users[ currentUsers[ ids[1].id ] ] && users[ ids[1].id ]';
var operators = ['&','|','+','-','=','/','*'];
var answer = [];

parseBrackets(0);

function parseBrackets(start) {
    var openBrackets = 0;
    var currentString = '';
    for (var i = start; i < toParse.length; i++) {
        if (toParse[i] == '[') {  // open bracket
            if (openBrackets == 0) {
                parseBrackets(i + 1);
            }
            currentString += toParse[i];
            openBrackets++;
        } else if (toParse[i] == ']' && openBrackets-- == 0) { // close bracket
            answer.push(currentString);
            return;
        } else if (operators.indexOf(toParse[i]) >= 0) { // this is an expression operator, don't include it
            if (currentString != '') {
                answer.push(currentString);
            }
            currentString = '';
        } else { // add this character to the current string
            currentString += toParse[i];
        }
    }
    answer.push(currentString); // add the current string to the list of parsed 'dependencies'
}

console.log(answer);
```

Here it is in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W87m3/5/

Here is the output:

```
 ["1", " ids[1].id ", " currentUsers[ ids[1].id ] ", "collections.users[ currentUsers[ ids[1].id ] ] ", "1", " ids[1].id ", " users[ ids[1].id ]"]
```

Comment: I have tried that, (number 2 in question), however it's easier said than done

Comment: I like this approach, the trick is to recover (and keep going) from an un-balanced condition.

Comment: @Connor I edited the post and added coded to do what I was describing. I believe it solves your needs.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this fails when you try different expressions, I've tried for the past 10 hours to extend it and get it working, it just doesn't seem very possible

Comment: @Connor Do you have an example of an expression it fails on? It meets the criteria you laid out in your question. If I have more information, maybe I can help you tweak it for what you need.

Comment: @sixthsmith For example it fails if you use anything other than `&&` I'm gonna keep trying at it

Comment: Are you saying that in addition to `&&` you want to support `||`? Anything else? Do you want those to behave differently? If you just want them parsed the same, you would just need to add those symbols on the line that checks for the `&` character. I believe I did answer your original question though...

Comment: @sixthsmith it is a javascript expression

Comment: @Connor I modified my answer above to handle everything in the operators array: `var operators = ['&','|','+','-','=','/','*'];`. It should work for you now. Let me know if you still have any trouble with specific expressions.

Comment: If some of those symbols should not actually be in the array (ie, you want to include the arithmetic operators between brackets), you should be able to just remove them from the operators array and they will be included in the parsed text.

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem, I took some inspiration from your answer thanks, bounty in 2 hours

Answer (score 1):

Regexp is not suitable for this problem, because regexp cannot "count". I.e. no matter how complex your regexp will be there will be some level of bracket nesting that will not be accepted.

What you realy need is a parser. There are some parser generators that are generating the code using grammar rules. Here are some: [Javascript parser generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211111/javascript-parser-generator).

Your rules looks pretty simple. Something like this:

```
Expression = AnythingExceptBrackets '[' Expression ']' AnythingExceptBrackets 
             | AnythingExceptBrackets 

AnythingExceptBrackets = [^\\[\\]]+
```

When you got the generator the only step left is to paste recognized tokens into result array.

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse the phrase successfully the full structure of the phrase has to be known. It is impossible to determine all possible structures from the one example given. However making some assumptions I have defined a possible structure using Extended Backus–Naur Form (EBNF).

The assumptions are that each array element can have as index an integer, a variable or another array element and variables and array elements can have properties written using the dot notation. The list of array elements can have operators between them.

This structure you can then alter and extend as needed.

Extended Backus–Naur Form Notation

{ } 0 or more

[ ] 1 or more

( ) group

letter = "a"|"b"|"c....."|"x"|"y"|"z"|"A"|"B"|"....."|"Y"|"Z"

digit = 0"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"7"|"8"|"9

integer = [digit]

term = [char|digit]

identifier = ($|_|char){term}

property = .char{term}

variable = identifier{property}

index=digit|variable|digit

array = variable"["index"]"{property}

operator = "&&"|"||"|+"|"-"|"*"|"/"

phrase = array{operator array}:

There is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5ErK/1/) which parses a phrase and produces the results for the given example

The code is

```
letter = /[a-zA-Z]/;
digit = /[0-9]/;
join = /[&|+\-*]/;  //possible operators


var phrase=' collections.users[ currentUsers[ ids[1].id ] ] && users[ ids[1].id ]';
var ptr=0;
var stack=[];

phrase=phrase.replace(/\s/g,''); //remove extraneous white space
phrase+=':'; //add : as terminator

var crctr=readNext();

getArray();         
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=setResults();

function getArray() {
    var L=new List();
    L.name=getVariable();
    L.index=getIndex();
    crctr=readNext();
    if(crctr=='.') {
        crctr=readNext();
        L.property=getProperty();
    }   
    stack.push(L);
    if(crctr !=':') { //not end of phrase
        if (join.test(crctr)) {     
            readJoin();         
            getArray();
        }
    }
}

function getIndex() {
    var indx='';
    if(crctr=="[") {
        crctr=readNext();   
        if(digit.test(crctr))
        {
            indx=getInteger();
            if(crctr==']') {
                return indx;
            }
        }
        else {
            indx=getVariable(); 
            if(crctr=="]"){
                return indx;
            }
            else if(crctr=="[") {                   
                var L=new List();
                L.name=indx;
                L.index=getIndex();
                crctr=readNext();
                if(crctr=='.') {
                    crctr=readNext();
                    L.property=getProperty();
                }
                stack.push(L);          
                return L;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        throw 'index error';
    }
}



function getVariable() {
    var v="";   
    if(crctr=="$" || crctr=="_" || letter.test(crctr)) {
        v+=crctr;
        crctr=readNext();
        v+=getIdentifier();
        if (crctr==".") {
            v+=crctr;
            crctr=readNext();
            v+=getProperty();
        }
        return v;   
    }
    else {
        throw 'variable error';
    }
}

function getIdentifier() {
    var id="";
    if(crctr=="$" || crctr=="_" || letter.test(crctr)) {
        id=crctr;
        crctr=readNext();
        id+=getTerm();
        return id;  
    }
    else {
        throw 'Identifier error';
    }
}

function getTerm() {
    var t="";
    while(letter.test(crctr) || digit.test(crctr)) {
        t+=crctr;
        crctr=readNext();
    }
    return t;
}

function getProperty() {
    var p='';
    if(letter.test(crctr)) {
        p=crctr;
        crctr=readNext();
        while(letter.test(crctr) || digit.test(crctr)) {
            p+=crctr;
            crctr=readNext();
        }
        if(crctr=='.') {
            p+=crctr;
            crctr=readNext();
            p+=getProperty();
        }
        else {
            return p;
        }
    }
    else {
        throw 'property error';
    }
}

function getInteger() {
    var i='';
    while(digit.test(crctr)) {
        i+=crctr;
        crctr=readNext();
    }
    return i;
}

function readJoin() {
    if(crctr=="&" || crctr=="|") {
        crctr=readNext();
    }
    crctr=readNext();
}

function readNext(){
    var crctr=phrase.charAt(ptr);
    ptr+=1;
    return crctr;
}

function List() {
    this.name='';
    this.index='';
    this.property='';
}

function setResults() {
    var r='results = [';
    while(stack.length>1) {
        var A=stack.pop();
        r+='<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+listArrays(A)+',';
    }
    var A=stack.pop();
    r+='<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+listArrays(A);
    return r+='<br>]';
}

function listArrays(A) {        
    if(A.index.name) { //A.index is array   
        var name=A.name;
        var indx=A.index;
        var prp='';
        if(A.property !='') {
            prp='.'+A.property;
        }
        return A.name+'['+listArrays(A.index)+']'+prp;
    }
    else {
        var name=A.name;
        var indx=A.index;
        var prp='';
        if(A.property !='') {
            prp='.'+A.property;
        }
        return A.name+'['+A.index+']'+prp;
    }
}
```

This puts the results in a div `<div id='results'></div>`

The code will need testing on the other examples you have.